# Database locking issue with QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I'm developing a PyQt app that shows data from SQLite database using `QTableView` and `QSqlTableModel`. The main view is designed to be read-only. The user can launch an editor to edit the values in the database. The editor uses `sqlite3` to make changes in the database. (Due to Qt's awkward type conversions between C++ and Python, I don't want to use the Qt database API in the editor).

My problem: when trying to make changes to the database in the editor, I receive `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`. I managed to figure out that this is due to `QTableView` holding a lock on the database due to its lazy fetch characteristic (it only fetches 256 rows and then leaves a lock on the database connection). More info at [this link](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/58280-Does-QDataWidgetMapper-lock-sqlite-and-prevent-write-by-other-applications).

I've come up with the following solutions:

- close the Qt database connection before launching the editor - not ideal, since it prevents the main window from working while the editor is open
- clear the `QSqlTableModel` instance before launching the editor - same problem as above
- use `QSqlTableModel.fetchMore()` to fetch all data before launching the editor - this seems to release the lock, but if the main window is still operable, I guess the lock could be re-established at any time, preventing further writes?
- make a new class by subclassing `QSqlTableModel` or `QAbstractItemModel` and control the locking myself

Before I go with the last one, are there any easier options?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "awkward type conversions", I believe you can override them using `QItemDelegate`.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I discovered if you have NULLs in your database, PyQt will return them as empty strings, and you can no longer tell them apart from actual empty strings in the database. This is since C++ `QtVariant` types are "smartly" autoconverted to Python types. This can be worked around, but it's enough to stop me from using the PyQt database API. (Also, using `sqlite3` instead results in much nicer code).

Comment: Using two connections instead on one and rewriting whats already in `QSqlTable` (updating and caching), which in turn create complications, does not seem nice code to me.

Comment: SQLite is a wonderful tool, both quick and lightweight. But it does not support well multiple accesses to the same database. IMHO, you have a major general design problem here. It can be solved by using a heavier database engine like PostgreSQL or MariaDB, or having the editor to not directly access the database or... But having more than one process accessing the same SQLite database can later the the source for maintenance nightmares...

Comment: @JussiNurminen The issue with NULL values can be solved very easily, which is explained in the PyQt docs: [Support for QVariant](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt_qvariant.html). In short, you can suppress auto-conversion like this: `sip.enableautoconversion(QVariant, False); ... # do stuff that returns variant values ...; sip.enableautoconversion(QVariant, True)`. This will temporarily return the values as a wrapped QVariant instead of python types, so you can then use `value.isNull()`, etc.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes I know, but no thanks. I'd rather have my database operations work without such "surprises" (this took me couple of hours to debug). Also, as I said, with `sqlite3` the code turned out about 100 times nicer than equivalent `QSql` code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta can you elaborate? What kind of nightmares? So far it seems to work exactly like described in SQlite docs: multiple reader processes coexist happily and hold `SHARED` locks while reading, while writer processes need `EXCLUSIVE` locks (and cannot coexist with `SHARED` locks).

Comment: @JussiNurminen Well, you must be doing something very wrong if there really is a "100 times" difference in your code. The isolated issue with NULLs seems far too trivial to account for it, so I assume you must be exaggerating somewhat ;-)

Comment: @ekhumoro exaggeration is the spice of life

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing `QSqlTableModel` in the following way. It seems to prevent the locking from occuring.

```
class NonLazyQSqlTableModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    """QSqlTableModel without the prefetch feature.

    This works for small tables. The purpose is to prevent SQL locking that
    occurs with prefetch.
    """

    def fetchMore(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> None:
        """Whenever fetchMore is called, we fetch everything"""
        while super().canFetchMore():
            super().fetchMore()
```